# Application layer connection when using apt-get install

Tags: networking, apt

I know By type `sudo apt-get install myprogram`, I can download and install myprogram from repositories. By calling this command in terminal which kind of application layer connection  will be established?

I guess in transport layer it will make a TCP connection but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get` use TCP in general, but to know exactly which protocol `apt-get` is using, you can have a look at the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Packages can be coming from a cd-rom, a ftp server, a http server, etc.

Comment: thanks for /etc/apt/sources.list . I thought I should use wireshark :-(

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get` and APT will use whatever protocol the sources are into. He doesn't care how these are transported. It could be HTTP, HTTPS, RSYNC, FTP, BitTorrent, etc. Most of them are TCP based, some are UDP. It totally depends of the protocol you are using.